# How can I assign NA?

Tags: r, if-statement, na

I use the **mtcars** dataframe and I use the following code to assign `NA` to all the values of columns `drat` and `wt` <=3.

```
df <- mtcars %>%
mutate(across(c(drat, wt), ~ifelse(.x<=3, NA, .x)))
```

How can I modify the code in a way that let me to assign `NA` also to the values of the column `qsec` if the value of `drat` or `wt` in the same row is <=3? At the end I want that each row where `drat` or `wt` is `NA` has `NA` also in the column `qsec`. Thanks

Comment: Did you meant if any of those column or is it both?  In the dataset, the `&` condition is not met

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We may use `if_any` on the columns that are changed to `NA` to return a logical vector to replace values in 'qsec'

```
library(dplyr)
mtcars1 <- mtcars %>%
      mutate(across(c(drat, wt), ~ifelse(.x<=3, NA, .x)),
    qsec = ifelse(if_any(c(drat, wt), is.na), NA, qsec))
```

-output

```
> head(mtcars1)
                   mpg cyl disp  hp drat    wt  qsec vs am gear carb
Mazda RX4         21.0   6  160 110 3.90    NA    NA  0  1    4    4
Mazda RX4 Wag     21.0   6  160 110 3.90    NA    NA  0  1    4    4
Datsun 710        22.8   4  108  93 3.85    NA    NA  1  1    4    1
Hornet 4 Drive    21.4   6  258 110 3.08 3.215 19.44  1  0    3    1
Hornet Sportabout 18.7   8  360 175 3.15 3.440 17.02  0  0    3    2
Valiant           18.1   6  225 105   NA 3.460    NA  1  0    3    1
```

Answer (score 4):

**1) dplyr** Continue the mutate to set qsec to NA if either drat or wt is NA. (If you meant *and* rather than *or* then replace | with & .)

```
mtcars %>%
  mutate(across(c(drat, wt), ~ifelse(.x<=3, NA, .x)),
         qsec = ifelse(is.na(drat) | is.na(wt), NA, qsec))
```

giving:

```
                     mpg cyl  disp  hp drat    wt  qsec vs am gear carb
Mazda RX4           21.0   6 160.0 110 3.90    NA    NA  0  1    4    4
Mazda RX4 Wag       21.0   6 160.0 110 3.90    NA    NA  0  1    4    4
Datsun 710          22.8   4 108.0  93 3.85    NA    NA  1  1    4    1
Hornet 4 Drive      21.4   6 258.0 110 3.08 3.215 19.44  1  0    3    1
Hornet Sportabout   18.7   8 360.0 175 3.15 3.440 17.02  0  0    3    2
Valiant             18.1   6 225.0 105   NA 3.460    NA  1  0    3    1
Duster 360          14.3   8 360.0 245 3.21 3.570 15.84  0  0    3    4
Merc 240D           24.4   4 146.7  62 3.69 3.190 20.00  1  0    4    2
Merc 230            22.8   4 140.8  95 3.92 3.150 22.90  1  0    4    2
Merc 280            19.2   6 167.6 123 3.92 3.440 18.30  1  0    4    4
Merc 280C           17.8   6 167.6 123 3.92 3.440 18.90  1  0    4    4
Merc 450SE          16.4   8 275.8 180 3.07 4.070 17.40  0  0    3    3
Merc 450SL          17.3   8 275.8 180 3.07 3.730 17.60  0  0    3    3
Merc 450SLC         15.2   8 275.8 180 3.07 3.780 18.00  0  0    3    3
Cadillac Fleetwood  10.4   8 472.0 205   NA 5.250    NA  0  0    3    4
Lincoln Continental 10.4   8 460.0 215   NA 5.424    NA  0  0    3    4
Chrysler Imperial   14.7   8 440.0 230 3.23 5.345 17.42  0  0    3    4
Fiat 128            32.4   4  78.7  66 4.08    NA    NA  1  1    4    1
Honda Civic         30.4   4  75.7  52 4.93    NA    NA  1  1    4    2
Toyota Corolla      33.9   4  71.1  65 4.22    NA    NA  1  1    4    1
Toyota Corona       21.5   4 120.1  97 3.70    NA    NA  1  0    3    1
Dodge Challenger    15.5   8 318.0 150   NA 3.520    NA  0  0    3    2
AMC Javelin         15.2   8 304.0 150 3.15 3.435 17.30  0  0    3    2
Camaro Z28          13.3   8 350.0 245 3.73 3.840 15.41  0  0    3    4
Pontiac Firebird    19.2   8 400.0 175 3.08 3.845 17.05  0  0    3    2
Fiat X1-9           27.3   4  79.0  66 4.08    NA    NA  1  1    4    1
Porsche 914-2       26.0   4 120.3  91 4.43    NA    NA  0  1    5    2
Lotus Europa        30.4   4  95.1 113 3.77    NA    NA  1  1    5    2
Ford Pantera L      15.8   8 351.0 264 4.22 3.170 14.50  0  1    5    4
Ferrari Dino        19.7   6 145.0 175 3.62    NA    NA  0  1    5    6
Maserati Bora       15.0   8 301.0 335 3.54 3.570 14.60  0  1    5    8
Volvo 142E          21.4   4 121.0 109 4.11    NA    NA  1  1    4    2
```

**2) Base R** With base R we can use `within` like this giving the same result.

```
within(mtcars, {
  drat <- ifelse(drat <= 3, NA, drat)
  wt <- ifelse(wt <= 3, NA, wt)
  qsec <- ifelse(is.na(drat) | is.na(wt), NA, qsec)
})
```

or at the expense of some redundancy we could use `transform`:

```
transform(mtcars,
  drat = ifelse(drat <= 3, NA, drat), 
  wt = ifelse(wt <= 3, NA, wt),
  qsec = ifelse(drat <= 3 | wt <= 3, NA, qsec))
```

Answer (score 2):

Since the question is not tagged `tidyverse` here is a base R way with `is.na<-`.

```
is.na(mtcars$drat) <- mtcars$drat < 3
is.na(mtcars$wt) <- mtcars$wt < 3
is.na(mtcars$qsec) <- with(mtcars, is.na(drat) | is.na(wt))
```